# Header slot components configuration not reflecting in Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Below header slot configuration does not have any impact in the site. added below config in app.module.ts file, but footer config with slots:[] removes the footer section.

```
imports: [
ConfigModule.withConfig({
  layoutSlots: {
    header: {
      slots: ['SiteLogo', 'MiniCart', 'SearchBox', 'NavigationBar']
    },
    footer: {
      slots: []
    }
  },
} as LayoutConfig),
BrowserModule,
```

Any suggestions plz?  FYI, Using Spartacus 4.0.0 with Hybris 1905

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at source code:

https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/release/4.0.0/projects/storefrontlib/src/recipes/config/layout-config.ts

you will see the slots assignment for header is configured per break point ( screen layout ). Spartacus allows for an adaptive configuration for each breakpoint. A specific slot configuration can be provided for each breakpoint.

```
 layoutSlots: {
    header: {
      lg: {
        slots: [
          'PreHeader',
          'SiteContext',
          'SiteLinks',
          'SiteLogo',
          'SearchBox',
          'SiteLogin',
          'MiniCart',
          'NavigationBar',
        ],
      },
      slots: ['PreHeader', 'SiteLogo', 'SearchBox', 'MiniCart'],
    },
```

So for your case, please put slot configuration under lg(large screen) break point, as code below.

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
      layoutSlots: {
      header: {
        slots: [],
        lg: {
          slots: ['SiteLogo']
        }
      },
      footer: {
        slots: []
      }
  },
} as LayoutConfig)
```

Finally, in rendered storefront, there is only logo visible in header area. See screenshot:
[image]